# Intel RealSense Depth Camera D435i Wide Imager questions?

Tags: computer-vision, cameras, hardware

I have just ordered my d435i and while it was not intended to do NDVI I read the data sheet and noticed it had seperate image sensors, it is possible to read the IR image from either left, right or both wide imagers? if so, would this image only contain reflectance values from NIR spectrum ie. 650um above?

Comment: why don't you consult the user manual?

Comment: I have read the user-manual, I it wasn't apparent hence the "Question". 

Cheers Ben